# Mask does not work correct way at RobinHerbots inputmask plugin

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-inputmask

I have this input mask [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oqys6kk7/):

```
<input data-inputmask="'mask':'[[[[[9]9]9].9]9]9,--€','greedy':false,'numericInput':true" />
```

but I do not want thousand separator (dot) to be visible until user types in 4th digit. So, currently the input is:

```
 1,--€
 14,--€
 .145,--€
 1.450,--€
```

What I need is logical:

```
 1,--€
 14,--€
 145,--€
 1.450,--€
```

Other mask I tried does not allow 4th digit at all:

```
 [[[[[9]9]9.]9]9]9,--€
```

Currently I use simple mask:

```
 999.999,--€
```

...but I do not want complete mask to be visible **___.___,--€**

Is there a way to do this with [current library](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask)? Also, first number should not be zero, maybe regex is better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet may be to override the "numeric" alias, as follows:

```
<html>
: <!-- includes etc. -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#price").inputmask();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
Price: <input id="price" data-inputmask="'alias': 'numeric', 'groupSeparator': '.', 'autoGroup': true, 'digits': 2, 'digitsOptional': true, 'radixPoint': ',', 'suffix': ' €', 'placeholder': '0', 'min': '0', 'max': '99999'"  />
</body>
</html>
```

The options should be fairly self-explanatory, you can modify as needed. This differs from your problem in that cents are optional (and not always excluded). You may want to read a bit of the code, especially **jquery.inputmask.numeric.extensions.js**, from which you may learn somewhat. There is also an "integer" alias, which might work for what you want (adjusting suffix), but it does seem to have a bug.

Comment: I found out later that `inputmask` plugin has bugs on mobile devices and I had to change it. Currently I am using [maskmoney plugin](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney). Thank you for registering just to answer my question.